# Using CLGeocoder instead of private API in map view

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, clgeocoder

I was using google API to obtain the geo co-ordinates. The code I have been using till now is as below

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {

NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",
                    [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;

//NSLog(@"items array %@", items);

if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else {
    //NSLog(@"Address, %@ not found: Error %@",addressStr, [items objectAtIndex:0]);
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = latitude;
location.longitude = longitude;
return location;
}
```

I wish to use `CLGeocoder` in the place of google API to obtain the location co-ordinates from an address string.

I have been working with `CLGeocoder` seen from examples online. I find it a bit hard task  working with the `CLGeocoder`. I tried to use the `CLGeocoder` without changing much from my previous code, so that I don't have to make big changes in the existing code.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressStr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    self.placemarksArray = placemarks;
    CLPlacemark *placeInfo = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",placeInfo.location.coordinate.latitude ];
    NSString *longitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",placeInfo.location.coordinate.longitude ];
    NSLog(@"latitudeString %@", latitudeString);
    NSLog(@"longitudeString %@", longitudeString);

    _latitudes = placeInfo.location.coordinate.latitude;
    _longitudes = placeInfo.location.coordinate.longitude;
}];
location.latitude = _latitudes;
location.longitude = _longitudes;
return location;
```

But what happens is that, the map view gets loaded before the block is executed. The exact value of the location is not returned in this case.

My question is :

1. Is it possible to use `CLGeocoder`, without making much changes to my previous code. Or should I need to change the whole structure.
2. From the 2nd block of code I have tried, what I am I doing wrong and how may I correct it?

Edit: The above method is called from `viewDidLoad`

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCenter = [self getLocationFromAddressString:fullAddress];
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            [annotationPoint setCoordinate:mapCenter];
            [annotationPointsArray addObject:annotationPoint];
addAnnotation = [[[MyAddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapCenter title:firstName SubTitle:lastName]autorelease];

 [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
```

This gets executed after getting the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` latitude and longitude values from getGeoLocation method.

Comment: Ok, it appears that you're taking the `location` from `getLocationFromAddressString` and creating an annotation. You should (a) change `getLocationFromAddressString` to return `void` and (b) then put the code that creates the annotation in the `geocodeAddressString` completion block.

Comment: I was going the same way as u suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLGeocoder` happens asynchronously (the fact that it's done in a block gives that away), and thus `_latitudes` and `_longitudes` are not set by the time the method, itself, returns. So, likely, yes, some slight restructuring of your code will be needed. It's hard for us to advise as we don't see the code that calls this routine. Bottom line, you have to refactor that code so that rather than returning the `location`, you have the `completionHandler` of `geocodeAddressString` invoke whatever you need done.

Looking at your revised code, it appears that your `viewDidLoad` is taking the location coordinates and creating an annotation. Just do that adding of the annotation *inside* the geocoded block.

Thus:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) geocodeAddressString:(NSString*)addressStr title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] autorelease];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressStr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        self.placemarksArray = placemarks;
        CLPlacemark *placeInfo = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

        id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [[[MyAddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:placeInfo.location.coordinate 
                                                                                 title:title
                                                                              SubTitle:subtitle] autorelease];

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    }];
}
```

And then, `viewDidLoad` would call it as follows:

```
[self geocodeAddressString:fullAddress title:firstName subtitle:lastName];
```

Comment: One question I have is regarding the Title and subtitle information. The only way it seems, I can pass this data to the annotation object is through the address string parameter? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @XaviValero Just add additional parameters to the method. See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of magic, but you have to poke your mapview, inside your block:

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = placeInfo.location.coordinate //or equivalent of this, like latitudes and longitudes change
```

If you want to avoid the mapview being drawn twice, you need to intercept events of [MKMapview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW4) (especially [mapViewWillStartLoadingMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW7)), implement them within your code, and put proper flags to avoid the map being drawn till the time reverse geocoding block hasn't been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer.

Call method with some part of delay (i.e. 2 seconds).

```
[self performSelector:@selector(geoCodeUsingAddress:) withObject:userAddress afterDelay:2.0];
```

Calling **GetCurrentLocation** function

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)addressStr
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressStr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
       self.placemarksArray = placemarks;
       CLPlacemark *placeInfo = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

       NSString *latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",placeInfo.location.coordinate.latitude ];
       NSString *longitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",placeInfo.location.coordinate.longitude ];

       NSLog(@"latitudeString %@", latitudeString);
       NSLog(@"longitudeString %@", longitudeString);

       _latitudes = placeInfo.location.coordinate.latitude;
       _longitudes = placeInfo.location.coordinate.longitude;
    }];

    location.latitude = _latitudes;
    location.longitude = _longitudes;

    return location;
}
```

Hopefully, it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Its a void method and you are returning a value.

How will it help if the method itself is being called after delay?

Comment: @XaviValero: Sorry, it was my mistake for returning value from void function. Now, I've edited, try if it'll helpful to you.